# Get the latest price SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table which contain _id, underSubheadId, wefDate, price.
Whenever a product is created or price is edited an entry is made in this table also.
What I want is if I enter a date, I get the latest price of all distinct UnderSubheadIds before the date (or on that date if no entry found)

```
_id underHeadId wefDate   price
1      1      2016-11-01    5 
2      2      2016-11-01    50
3      1      2016-11-25    500
4      3      2016-11-01    20 
5      4      2016-11-11    30
6      5      2016-11-01    40
7      3      2016-11-20    25
8      5      2016-11-15    52
```

If I enter 2016-11-20 as date I should get

```
1  5   
2  50
3  25
4  30
5  52
```

I have achieved the result using ROW NUMBER function in SQL SERVER, but I want this result in Sqlite which don't have such function.
Also if a date like 2016-10-25(which have no entries) is entered I want the price of the date which is first. 
Like for 1 we will get price as 5 as the nearest and the 1st entry is 2016-11-01.

This is the query for SQL SERVER which is working fine. But I want it for Sqlite which don't have ROW_NUMBER function.

```
select underSubHeadId,price from(
    select underSubHeadId,price, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By underSubHeadId order by wefDate desc) rn from rates
    where wefDate<='2016-11-19') newTable
where newTable.rn=1
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky, but here is one way:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.wefDate = (select max(t2.wefDate)
                   from t t2
                   where t2.underSubHeadId = t.underSubHeadId and
                         t2.wefdate <= '2016-11-20'
                  );
```

Comment: I just ran this query, but I am getting the same result as Select * from t.
All the rows are returned. :( @Gordon Linoff
Have a look http://imgur.com/a/OeMhF

Comment: @RishiChandak . . . Are you sure the correlation clause is correct?

Comment: I am not sure. But the query you suggested returned all the rows. The image link is provided in the last comment.
Thank you already.

Comment: Kindly see the question once again, I have edited and entered the query which was working in SQL SERVER.

Comment: @RishiChandak . . . You are partitioning by `underSubHeadId`.  That is the same column that should be used for the correlation clause.

Comment: Hey this worked. But when the amount of entries increases it would take lot of time to compare each row with each as in O(n2), If I am not wrong :p

Comment: @RishiChandak . . . An index on `t(underSubHeadId, underSubHeadId)` would help.

Answer (score 0):

select underHeadId, max(price)
from t
where wefDate <= "2016-11-20"
group by underHead;

Comment: I dont want the max price of date, but for the last price entry from that date.

Comment: I doubt if you understand sql.

Comment: You know, this is what I felt about you when I saw this query of yours.
Dude this query will return the max price of the UnderHeadId before that date. But this is not the value I want, what I want is the last updated value of that UnderHead before that date.